# Making saddle work with hdf5

Tags: scala, hdf5, saddle

I'm trying to work with hdf5 storage from [saddle](https://github.com/saddle/saddle). The first thing I tried was actually running tests from the project. Unfortunately they just hang:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /home/folone/workspace/saddle/project
[info] Set current project to saddle (in build file:/home/folone/workspace/saddle/)
[saddle]$ project saddle-hdf5
[info] Set current project to saddle-hdf5 (in build file:/home/folone/workspace/saddle/)
[saddle-hdf5]$ test
[warn] Credentials file /home/folone/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
[warn] Credentials file /home/folone/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
[1]    22192 killed     sbt
```

I tried playing with it from the repl. No luck:

```
> console
[warn] Potentially incompatible versions of dependencies of {file:/home/folone/workspace/ad-ngrams/}adngrams:
[warn]    org.scala-lang: 2.10.1, 2.10.0
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.1 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_21).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import org.saddle.io._
import org.saddle.io._

scala> java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.loadLibrary("jhdf5")

scala> val file = H5Store.openFile("/home/folone/workspace/ad-ngrams/temporary_store_ad.h5")
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ncsa.hdf.hdf5lib.HDF5Constants.H5_QUARTER_HADDR_MAX()J
    at ncsa.hdf.hdf5lib.HDF5Constants.H5_QUARTER_HADDR_MAX(Native Method)
    at ncsa.hdf.hdf5lib.HDF5Constants.<clinit>(HDF5Constants.java:35)
    at org.saddle.io.H5Store$.openFile(H5Store.scala:409)
    at .<init>(<console>:10)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:734)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:983)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:604)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:568)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.reallyInterpret$1(ILoop.scala:745)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:790)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:702)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine$1(ILoop.scala:566)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.innerLoop$1(ILoop.scala:573)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:576)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:867)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:822)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:822)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:822)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.main(ILoop.scala:889)
    at xsbt.ConsoleInterface.run(ConsoleInterface.scala:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:73)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.console(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:64)
    at sbt.Console.console0$1(Console.scala:23)
    at sbt.Console$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Console.scala:24)
    at sbt.TrapExit$.executeMain$1(TrapExit.scala:33)
    at sbt.TrapExit$$anon$1.run(TrapExit.scala:42)


scala> val fid1 = H5Store.createFile("/home/folone/workspace/ad-ngrams/test.h5")
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class ncsa.hdf.hdf5lib.HDF5Constants
    at org.saddle.io.H5Store$.createFile(H5Store.scala:433)
    at .<init>(<console>:10)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:734)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:983)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:604)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:568)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.reallyInterpret$1(ILoop.scala:745)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:790)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:702)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine$1(ILoop.scala:566)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.innerLoop$1(ILoop.scala:573)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:576)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:867)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:822)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:822)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:822)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.main(ILoop.scala:889)
    at xsbt.ConsoleInterface.run(ConsoleInterface.scala:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:73)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.console(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:64)
    at sbt.Console.console0$1(Console.scala:23)
    at sbt.Console$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Console.scala:24)
    at sbt.TrapExit$.executeMain$1(TrapExit.scala:33)
    at sbt.TrapExit$$anon$1.run(TrapExit.scala:42)
```

I have [this package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/jhdf5/) installed in my system and these lines in my sbt build config's library dependencies:

```
...
// Saddle
"org.scala-saddle" %% "saddle-core" % "1.2.+",
"org.scala-saddle" %% "saddle-hdf5" % "1.2.+",
"org.scala-saddle" %% "jhdf5"       % "2.9",
...
```

What do I need to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: If you just need HDF5 access, have a look at [NetCDF Java](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf-java/). Apart from NetCDF, it claims to support HDF5 as well, and it has the big advantage of being pure Java, so no crappy C linker errors and such. I have used this successfully with Scala, although only with NetCDF format files.

Comment: NetCDF works to some extent. For example, I've not been able to read an HDF5  generated in Matlab with it.

Comment: Also, Saddle is in its current state (v 1.3.4) more a HDF5 driver to dump Series and Frames to disk, than a full HDF5 wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full instructions here - http://blog.adamdklein.com/?p=661

In sum:

If you run sbt -> console, and look at your java.library.path, you’ll probably see something like this:

```
scala> println(System.getProperty("java.library.path")) 
.:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
```

So I added some symlinks to /usr/lib/java:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     78 Jul  8 13:29 libjhdf5.jnilib@ -> <dir>/libjhdf5.jnilib
```

Where dir is replaced with the path to the hdf5 binary library.

Note for Saddle, you only need libjhdf5.jnilib

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking into this. For me `System.getProperty("java.library.path")` says `/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib`. And I have jhdf5 installed in `/usr/lib/libjhdf5.so`. Adding symlinks to `.so` files from prebuilt binaries did not change anything. I also don't see any files with `.jnilib` extension neither in `/usr/lib` nor in the prebuilt binaries. Also, running `java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.loadLibrary("jhdf5")` does not produce any exceptions.

Comment: For future lurkers, Adam helped me figure this out in google groups here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/saddle/PrHBmpkGex4.